# jQuery/AJAX issue

Tags: jquery, web, webserver, hosting

After multiple call to AJAX function, I noticed a very large number of processes lanced and my website is blocked (in localhost there is not problem it work good).

What is the relation between jquery call and the processes or the security of the hosting who block it? (I have this problem in chat and upvote and downvote function).

Comment: Question needs a lot more specific details and the problematic code for anyone to be able to help. Right now it isn't even clear what `blocked` or `very large number of processes lanced` means. When you update question include any error details from browser console also

Comment: hello , sorry for my bad english , when exemple in the site , I click  upvote, then downvote ... for 30 seconde or any thing linked to jQuery the Site shutdown from my side , and when I see  in the cpanel the process started its like  40 / 100 .. while only me in the serveur !

Comment: show us the code used

Comment: Well probably you do have the code in your site files. What is happening on server won;t help a lot without seeing why so many calls to server are being made. That being said ... there could also be problems in the server code also

Comment: thanks for help dude,  tommorow you will be online or u have email or something i can contact you with from the office when am with the developper because him who write the code so you will understand him better

Comment: sure..post another comment here and I'll see it

Comment: var auto_refresh3 = setInterval(
  function ()
  {
 //tchata2.php is a file checking the new messages 
 $.post("tchata2.php",{FID:identif},function (data){
      if($('#newmsg').val()!=data){
       $('#newmsg').empty();
       $("#newmsg").append(data); 
      }
      
    });
  }, 1000); // checking for other messages after 1 second

Answer (score 0):

```
     var auto_refresh3 = setInterval( function () { 
            //tchata2.php is a file checking the new messages  
             $.post("tchata2.php",{FID:identif},function (data){
                          if($('#newmsg').val()!=data){ 
                                $('#newmsg').empty(); 
                                $("#newmsg").append(data);
                          } 
             });
      }, 1000); // checking for other messages after 1 second
```